# Flutter linux build on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS CMake Error

Tags: flutter, ubuntu, flutter-desktop, flutter-linux

I have flutter project and can be build successfully on Ubuntu 20.04. Now I want to build it on Ubuntu 22.04 but I got CMake Error.

```
CMake Error at /snap/flutter/111/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/clang++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/arzak/StudioProjects/testlinux/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ninja" "cmTC_38e6c"
    [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_38e6c.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    [2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_38e6c
    FAILED: cmTC_38e6c 
    : && /snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/clang++    -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8 -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lblkid -lgcrypt -llzma -lpthread -ldl -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ CMakeFiles/cmTC_38e6c.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTC_38e6c   && :
    /snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0008002
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1: undefined reference to `_dl_find_object@GLIBC_2.35'
    //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0: undefined reference to `__libc_single_threaded@GLIBC_2.32'
    //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock@GLIBC_2.34'
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
```

I've installed clang and others using `sudo apt-get install clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev`

this is the `flutter doctor` results

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.0, on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 5.15.0-27-generic,
    locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    32.1.0-rc1)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at
    google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @KenWhite, Thanks for the suggestion. I've found the answer on https://github.com/canonical/flutter-snap/issues/45#issuecomment-900688719.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [Pkrarakal](https://github.com/pkarakal), I follow his [suggestion](https://github.com/canonical/flutter-snap/issues/45#issuecomment-900688719) and the error was gone.
Try this steps :

- moving to edge channel, `snap refresh flutter --edge`
- running `flutter upgrade`
- deleting build directory `rm -r build/`
- running the application again flutter `flutter run -d linux`

Comment: I needed to install Flutter manually as I've added flutter_secure_storage to the project. After removing the Flutter snap I was not able to run the Linux app with error '/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ninja--version no such file or directory'.  Removing build directory helped me to resolve this issue